# MySQL - syncing large staging table with production table

Tags: mysql, synchronization, database-partitioning

I have a table with 4mil+ records. There is a staging table that gets updated with data via an ETL process throughout the day. Once the staging table gets updated, I need to then sync that data with the production table. I'm currently using an INSERT/ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE query to sync them, however with the size of this table it takes ~750 seconds to run. Is there a more efficient way to update/insert the new data? I have read some about partitioning tables, but I'm not sure if that's what I need to do or not. Can anyone give me some suggestions on how to do accomplish this more efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the maatkit tools (http://www.maatkit.org/), specifically http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-table-sync.html.  It is pretty efficient at this sort of thing.